# Strsplit on a column of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a `data.frame` where one of the variables is a vector (or a list), like this:

```
MyColumn <- c("A, B,C", "D,E", "F","G")
MyDF <- data.frame(group_id=1:4, val=11:14, cat=MyColumn)

#   group_id val    cat
# 1        1  11 A, B,C
# 2        2  12    D,E
# 3        3  13      F
# 4        4  14      G
```

I'd like to have a new data frame with as many rows as the vector

```
FlatColumn <- unlist(strsplit(MyColumn,split=","))
```

which looks like this:

```
MyNewDF <- data.frame(group_id=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2),3,4), val=c(rep(11,3),rep(12,2),13,14), cat=FlatColumn)

#   group_id val cat
# 1        1  11   A
# 2        1  11   B
# 3        1  11   C
# 4        2  12   D
# 5        2  12   E
# 6        3  13   F
# 7        4  14   G
```

In essence, for every factor which is an element of the list of `MyColumn` (the letters A to G), I want to assign the corresponding values of the list. Every factor appears only once in `MyColumn`.

Is there a neat way for this kind of reshaping/unlisting/merging? I've come up with a very cumbersome `for`-loop over the rows of `MyDF` *and* the length of the corresponding element of `strsplit(MyColumn,split=",")`. I'm very sure that there has to be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
lst <- strsplit(MyColumn, split = ",")
k <- lengths(lst)    ## expansion size
FlatColumn <- unlist(lst, use.names = FALSE)
MyNewDF <- data.frame(group_id = rep.int(MyDF$group_id, k),
                      val = rep.int(MyDF$val, k),
                      cat = FlatColumn)

#  group_id val cat
#1        1  11   A
#2        1  11   B
#3        1  11   C
#4        2  12   D
#5        2  12   E
#6        3  13   F
#7        4  14   G
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr`:

```
tidyr::separate_rows(MyDF, cat)

#   group_id val cat
# 1        1  11   A
# 2        1  11   B
# 3        1  11   C
# 4        2  12   D
# 5        2  12   E
# 6        3  13   F
# 7        4  14   G
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(MyDF, "cat", ",", "long")
#    group_id val cat
#1:        1  11   A
#2:        1  11   B
#3:        1  11   C
#4:        2  12   D
#5:        2  12   E
#6:        3  13   F
#7:        4  14   G
```

---

We can also use do with `base R` with `strsplit` to split the 'cat' column into a `list`, replicate the sequence of rows of 'MyDF' with the `lengths` of 'lst', and create the 'cat' column by `unlist`ing the 'lst'.

```
lst <- strsplit(as.character(MyDF$cat), ",")
transform(MyDF[rep(1:nrow(MyDF), lengths(lst)),-3], cat = unlist(lst))
```